# Q. If you compile and execute an application with the following code in its main() method: Why " s" is created two objects

Tags: java

If you compile and execute an application with the following code in its main() method:
In this program why the " s" create the two objects.

```
   String s = new String( "Computer" );

   if( s == "Computer" )
   System.out.println( "Equal A" );
   if( s.equals( "Computer" ) )
   System.out.println( "Equal B" );
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `s == "Computer"` test will fail, since `s` and the literal string `"Computer"` are sitting at different addresses.

The second `s.equals("Computer")` will succeed. The two strings have equal contents.

Any good tutorial book on Java would explain that better than we have time to.

Answer (score 0):

To compare String objects you should do:

```
if( s.equals("Computer" ))
```

instead of `==` operator.